# Javascript pass values to function on event listener

Tags: javascript

If I do the following the variable is passed to the attached event listener where as I want the value of the variable at the time the event listener is added passed.

```
foo=a;    
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function() { doSomething(foo) }, false); 
foo=b;

doSomething(val){
alert(val);
}
```

so it should alert "a" not "b";

Comment: What about creating a copy of the value when the event listener is added?

Comment: It has to be static as a number of buttons will be created.

Comment: the script is right when will alert "b" and not "a", because by the time the user clicks, foo has already value "b";
what you got there with addEventListener is you assign a function to that event, so when event is triggered the function is executed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

something like:

```
var foo = 'a';    

document
.getElementById('foo')
.addEventListener('click', function(bar) {

  // return the actual event handler function
  return function() {
    doSomething(bar);
  };

}(foo) /* <-- call the anonymous function, passing in the current foo*/, false); 

foo = 'b';

function doSomething (val) {
  alert(val);
}​
```

---

**demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gS9wu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since foo is global, then foo is overwritten on line 3 before the event is detected.

You may want to consider fetching the value of foo and storing it on an object or in a plugin or similar to abstract it away from your normal code flow or to pass it into the callback function:

document.addEventListener('mousedown',(function(outerFoo){ doSomething(outerFoo); })(foo), false);